# Laravel - Calculated query with join inside it

Tags: sql, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm beginning with Laravel ORM Eloquent and i would like to do a query with some calculated fields that depend on 2 tables.
So i have to do a subquery inside the calculated query but i don't know how to do that with the Eloquent query builder.

Example of query that i want to do :

```sql
select * , 
(select activites.id_activites from activites inner join insc_ses on insc_ses.id_activites=activites.id_activites where id_session=1 
and insc_ses.id_inscription=inscriptions.id_inscription) activite_session1, 
(select activites.id_activites from activites inner join insc_ses on insc_ses.id_activites=activites.id_activites where id_session=2 
and insc_ses.id_inscription=inscriptions.id_inscription) activite_session2, 
(select activites.id_activites from activites inner join insc_ses on insc_ses.id_activites=activites.id_activites where id_session=3 
and insc_ses.id_inscription=inscriptions.id_inscription) activite_session3 
from inscriptions
```

Is that possible to do ?

What i have already try which doesnt work :

```php
        $projets = \DB::table('projet')
                            ->select(
                                \DB::table('projet')->join('codif','projet.TYPE_PROJ_',"=","codif.CLECOD")
                                ->where('codif.CDCOD','=','TYPE_PROJ')
                                ->select('LIBCOD')->get())
                            ->select()->get();
```

Comment: What have you tried and didn't work?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would  help other people understand what you want to do.

Comment: i have try something that doesn't works i will edit my post to show you. What i want is to "select" the result of a subquery involving 2 tables

Comment: like created a new field in the select that is the result of a subquery

Comment: or is there a way to write brut sql query ?